# findById in Mongoose on a subdocument

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am attempting a findById in Mongoose on a subdocument....[posts]

How do i findById one specific [post] inside user?

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: String,
   content: String
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String,
    posts: [postSchema]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dot notation something like this

```
unique_id = req.params.id
const uniquePost = User
    .find({'posts._id':unique_id })
```

or if you hade a schema like this nesting

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String,   
    posts: {
    posts: postSchema
  }
});
```

you coulld again use dot notation to find the deeply nested id 
like so

```
const uniquePost = User
    .find({'posts.posts._id':unique_id })
```